# Forming a curve between two lines

Tags: matlab, curve

Can anyone let me know how should i go about creating a smooth curve in matlab

Problem statement: There are two straight line and i want to join them with a smooth curve. The dimensions of the curve are not limited to any specific dimensions. It is fine as long as there is a smooth continuity or the two lines are connected to each other by a smooth curve as shown in below figure

[image]

final Image

[image: Image Final]

I hope the problem statement is clear and please let me know incase if anything is not clear.

I am using the following code and being a beginner I know its not a prefect code and there maybe mistakes. I would be glad if anyone can let me know how can i implement this curve in the form of a code in matlab.

```
s=10;
vec=0.6;
i=0; x=0; y=0; z=0; x1=0; y1=0; z1=0;
for i=1:s
     x(i)=0;
     z(i)=i;
     y(i)=0;
end
angle=60;
j=0;
for j=1:s
if j<vec*s
     x1(j)=0;
     z1(j)=j;
     y1(j)=0;
end
if j>=vec*s
     x1(j)=x(j);
     y1(j)=(z(j)-vec*s)*sind(angle)+y(i)*cosd(angle);
     z1(j)=(z(j)-vec*s)*cosd(angle)-y(i)*sind(angle)+vec*s;
end
end
plot3(x1,y1,z1); xlabel('X axis'); ylabel('Y axis'); zlabel('Z axis');
```

Comment: You need to better define what you mean by "smooth curve between two lines". You could create a smooth curve which starts on one vector, goes twice around the globe and joins another vector with perfect continuity! Is it mathematical continuity you want, or just some visual rounding?

Comment: Yes.... I meant once a vector is finished, a smooth surve should be introduced and then it can be connected to other ventor.. Basically to have a continuity as shown in the picture(final Image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use parametric interpolation (with parameter `t`):

```
plot3(x1,y1,z1); xlabel('X axis'); ylabel('Y axis'); zlabel('Z axis');
hold on;
n = length(x1);
t = (1:n)';
v = [x1;y1;z1]';
idx = [1:3 n-2:n]; % points you want to preserve
plot3(x1(idx),y1(idx),z1(idx),'o');
pp = interp1(t(idx,:),v(idx,:),'spline','pp');
tt = linspace(1,n,100);
X = ppval(pp, tt);
plot3(X(:,1),X(:,2),X(:,3));
grid on
```

and you get:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much